# What is the difference between DASD and "Virtual" Tape

Tags: mainframe

What is the difference between DASD and Tape? I know that in the past, DASD was attributed to Hard Drive storage and Tape was actually magnetic tape. In our shop we are using "Virtual Tape" Which I am pretty sure is actually a hard drive.

The reason I am asking this question, is I have a job what requires a crazy amount of cylinders. We were advised by our storage guys to allocated 4300,4300 and that the system would be able to handle it as long as we released what we didn't use. As it turns out, the system was not able to reserve the cylinders that we required. So I was thinking of maybe using tape for the sequential files. This doesn't seem like a great solution because all of jobs are set up with GDG datasets (which can't be used on tape), so I wanted to try and find out what (if any) issues we would encounter before redesigning.

I am scared that we will run into the same issue trying to allocate a tape data set that big because if virtual tape and DASD are basically the same thing, it would stand to reason that the same error could occur when trying to reserve tape space of that size.

So can some explain to me the difference between DASD and Virtual Tape?

Comment: This site is for programming related questions. You're looking for [su] instead.

Comment: @KenWhite I kind of figured because this directly helps me solve a program issue I am having that it could have gone either way

Comment: I don't mind posting this question somewhere else, but right now there are 2 votes to close both suggesting I put the question on a different stack exchange site. I'll post it where ever is appropriate.

Comment: Don't worry about how virtual tape is implemented, from the point of view of everyone except the storage manager it's tape.  Also, when did GDGs and tape become incompatible?

Comment: @cschneid Im not sure, but someone at my shop told me that we can't allocate a GDG to a tape, its possible maybe they are wrong

Comment: GDG and tape is unproblematic, unless I've missed some major change (and it would never happen, as it would break far too many things). It doesn't matter is the answer what the difference is. Storage for virtual tape will likely not be coming from the same "pool" of space. If you have been told by the storage people to use 4300,4300, then you should go back to them. You may need to use a different storage group/class/something but only they will know how it is set up at the site. They need to fully understand your requirements for that amount of storage, and say how you reliably get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with DASD is that z/OS still thinks it is working with some kind of 3390-device with all its physical characteristics while the real storage-devices have totally different characteristics and far fewer restrictions.

So when you want to allocate 4300 cylinders the system wants to reserve a contiguous are of 4300 cylinders, which is about half of a 3390 model 9 device. So if you have to other datasets of one track each located at some unfavorable locations there might not be a sufficiently large contiguous free area and the allocation will fail.

If you start with an empty 3390 model 9 device you could succesfully allocate your dataset plus one additional extent, but the next extent would already require a multivolume-dataset. But it is unlikely your storage-group has reserved one volume only for your dataset.

The thing with (virtual) tapes is you always start out with a volume for your exculsive use, so there are no other datasets that could interfere with your space-needs.

So while the background-storage might be similar for DASD and virtual tape devices the operating-system imposes different (artificial) restrictions on them to emulate the behaviour of some legacy-devices.

Comment: Actually, if you allocate 4300 cylinders for a disk dataset, there's no requirement that it be contiguous unless you specifically asked for contiguous space using something such as the CONTIG parameter in JCL. Depending on the type of dataset and your allocation options, you can have up to 16 or 123 extents per disk volume, and of course, you can have multiple volumes.

Comment: Also, virtual tapes aren't limited to a single dataset per virtual volume. It's common to have "real" tapes with multiple datasets stacked on a single tape volume, and you can also do this with  virtual tapes. This is a carryover from days when long running jobs would use LABEL=2/3/... to stack datasets on tapes so that the human operator need not mount tape volumes over and over. Most of the virtual tape products can constrain the size of a "virtual volume", so you can still have out of space conditions on virtual tapes, especially when there are other datasets stacked on the same volume.

Answer (score 0):

"...GDG datasets (which can't be used on tape)..." Au contraire!  GDG datasets work GREAT with tape. There is NO restriction against creating a GDG version on Tape.